# Directx 9 Vertex Color on default objects like teapot

Tags: c++, directx, id3dxmesh

I've been playing around with directx for about a week now. I recently bump in to the default objects, and I played around with it. I can animate it, I can do alot with it, but I have no idea how to put vertex color(again not material). Default object is not really the right word to use so here are the list of functions that would generate these "default objects"

- D3DXCreateBox
- D3DXCreateSphere
- D3DXCreateCylinder
- D3DXCreateTeapot
- D3DXCreatePolygon
- D3DXCreateTorus

So can someone lay out the way on how to get the vertex buffers and then fill it with color data. I can do it with objects that I had to layout the vertex manually but not in these default mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HLSL Lang ..

> High-Level Shader Language. This is a script used by DirectX to
>   program specific portions of the rendering pipeline, giving a graphics
>   programmer a wide range of flexibility in special effects.